# Different estimates, same model when clustering standard errors R

Tags: r, na, glm, interaction, standard-error

I am estimating the same logistic regression (but with the variables in different order) using the glm package in R. All the variables are binary (one dependent variable, a co-variate, one interaction term). But depending on the order of the variables in the model, I get different results. Specifically, a NA for the standard error for one variable that I use in an interaction term ONLY when I cluster the standard errors. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here's my code:

```
mod1 <- glm(dv ~ cov + var1*var2,family binomial(link = "logit"),data = dat)
mod2 <- glm(dv ~ var1*var2 + cov,family = binomial(link = "logit"),data = dat)
stargazer(mod1,mod2)
```

Produces (output edited so easier to read):

```
cov & 0.300 & 0.300 \\ 
& (1.128) & (1.128) \\ 
var1 & $-$0.008 & $-$0.008 \\ 
 & (2,543.188) & (2,543.188) \\ 
var2 & 19.828 & 19.828 \\ 
 & (1,902.767) & (1,902.767) \\ 
var1:var2 & $-$0.569 & $-$0.569 \\ 
 & (2,543.188) & (2,543.188) \\
```

The results are the same above but they're different when I cluster the standard errors:

```
stargazer(coeftest(mod1,vcov = cluster.vcov(mod1, dat$groupid)),coeftest(mod2,vcov = cluster.vcov(mod2, dat$groupid)))
```

Produces:

```
cov & 0.300 & 0.300 \\ 
  & (1.073) & (1.073) \\ 
 var1 & $-$0.008 & $-$0.008 \\ 
  & (0.036) & NA \\ 
 var2 & 19.828$^{***}$ & 19.828$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.183) & (0.376) \\ 
 var1:var2 & $-$0.569 & $-$0.569 \\ 
  & (0.469) & (0.434) \\
```

Notice that here the standard error for `var1` is NA. I have no clue what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wrong venue. This is not the statistics help desk.

Comment: @42 Is this not an appropriate question?? It's an issue with R.

Comment: It's not an issue in R programming. It's an issue with how to interpret statistics output.

Comment: @42 But the package is producing different things for the same model, so that is an issue with R.

Comment: If you wrote two different functions in R and they gave two different answers, then it's NOT a question about R programming, but about your understanding of reality.

Comment: @42 But they aren't two different functions?? So it IS a question about a package in R. Maybe you should try reading it again.

Comment: I was reading the question as asking why results were different when you used `cluster.vcov`. That is what I meant by a "different" function. If that wasn't the question then you should clarify it with more detail, including sufficient data to actually run the code and compare output to what you are seeing but incompletely describing.

Comment: @42 I'm asking why when I use cluster.vcov the results are different for mod1 and mod2 when they are the same models.

Comment: They are not the same models. Models are not just a list of covariates. They are structured as a set of distributuinal assumptions, some of which involve the variances of the covariates. Your two calls have different assumptions about how variances are estimated and that difference will affect the fits. You need to talk to a statistician about this. It is not a programming question.